# Is it possible to see the source code of iOS SDK?

Tags: ios

Recently I have downloaded an iOS SDK from one website. When extracting that SDK, it contains the following items.

- libAppSDK.a
- AppLocalization folder
- AppModel.bundle
- AppResources.bundle
- AppHeader.h
- ReleaseNotes.txt

I knew that I can integrate this SDK (or framework??) with my application. But I want to see the source code of this SDK for some security purposes.

Can I see the source code of this SDK? If it is yes, can you explain the procedure?

Comment: If this "iOS SDK" is from a third party, then, no, you'll have to go that third party and ask for a copy of the source code.

Comment: Unless the third party has opened up the source code for you. The header files are the only info that is exposed, which is your case.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to ask the provider of the binaries for the source code.

If that's not possible you will have to reverse engineer. You can use [class dump](http://stevenygard.com/projects/class-dump/) to get all classes and methods.

otool is included with the developer tools and it will give you a lot of interesting information. `otool -tV libAppSDK.a` will disassemble the library for you. Use [Hopper](http://www.hopperapp.com) or [IDAPro](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/index.shtml) to get some help reverse engineering this.

The `.bundle` files are folders or zip files you can simply unpack and look inside.